# datetime causes incorrect date format even when babel is loaded first

Tags: babel, datetime, welsh

According to the package manual, `datetime` supports language-sensitive date formats provided that `babel` is loaded first. The example on page 2 is:

```
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
```

However, the following code produces incorrect results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[welsh]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\begin{document}

  \today

\end{document}
```

[image: Not entirely Welsh date]

Removing `datetime` produces a result which, while not actually correct, is at least less incorrect:

[image: Incomplete Welsh date]

I assume this is a bug. But is it a bug in `datetime` or `babel`'s support for Welsh or both? (Or something else but those seem the most likely possibilities.)

Clarification: the issue here is why I get different output in the two cases. The fact that `babel`'s translation is not perfect is a straightforward matter of incomplete localisation. What I'm asking about is why `a viz` is added when `datetime` is loaded. This is certainly not Welsh since the alphabet contains neither 'v' nor 'z' and, although 'a' is a Welsh word, it does not belong here.

My current hypothesis is that the bug is a joint effort. First, `babel` apparently omits to define Welsh ordinals. Second, `datetime` does not handle cases of impoverished language support appropriately. (Or there is just no way that `datetime` could do this. But I hope that is not so.)

Comment: By the way since we don't all speak Welsh, what is the correct/expected output? From looking at the code of [`datetime`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime), the Welsh output is coded that way...

Comment: @Werner I'd expect the same output I get without the `datetime` package i.e. `25 Medi 2014`. This could be improved but that's an issue of the translations/localisations provided by `babel` rather than any kind of interaction between the packages. It is the weird addition of `a viz` in the output which is really problematic. (Neither 'v' nor 'z' are in the Welsh alphabet and, while 'a' is a Welsh word, it does not belong here.) I've edited the question to try to make this a little clearer.

Comment: Since I don't speak Welsh, I implemented `datetime` to reproduce the same output as `babel`. (Similarly for all other supported languages.) Since this was done many years ago, it's possible `babel` has changed the output or I had some kind of brain failure while reading `babel`'s code. `datetime` was originally intended as a replacement for `ukdate` before `babel` existed and I regret not implementing a modular approach where each language module is maintained by someone fluent in that language. I'll fix `dt-welsh.def` to match `babel`.

Comment: I've just had a look at `welsh.dtx` and it has `\changes{welsh-1.0d}{2005/03/31}{removed \`a viz' from the definition of \cs{today}}` so `babel` used to produce the same output as `datetime`.

Comment: Clearly, the date for `welsh` was originally copypasted from `breton`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot The new version of `polyglossia` has been corrected to produce appropriate ordinals for Welsh. `babel`, `datetime` and `datetime2` are all still incorrect as far as I know.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I've posted a corrected version of `dt-welsh.def` as `dt-cymraeg.def` below. This is better Welsh and the standard date format works fine. However, I get spurious spacing with `\longdate` and `\shortdate` and am not sure how best to eliminate it. (Should I really be using maths mode for the superscripts here, even though dates are text, generally? I'm using `\textsuperscript{}` but I see you used maths mode for Breton.)

Comment: @cfr datetime is now obsolete so there won't be any further versions. The last version had the fix that removed the erroneous "a viz". It's been replaced by [datetime2](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) where the languages are dealt with by independently maintained modules, so the Welsh one is [datetime2-welsh](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-welsh) (currently unmaintained, but if you want to volunteer to take over, just send me a message).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Modified `datetime` works OKish for me, as long as I don't want a full date. `datetime2` I can't really get to grips with, I'm afraid. I have something which kind of works in a basic case, but it is so much more complicated and I don't have a good sense of how things fit together or what is supposed to do what (either in terms of files or in terms of commands). I couldn't possibly maintain it - I don't understand it well enough to get it working. In contrast, with `datetime`, it is really just the spacing problem I can't solve.

Answer (score 5):

The file `dt-welsh.def` seems to be at fault, for it does

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\datewelsh{%
\renewcommand{\formatdate}[3]{%
\@day=##1\relax\@month=##2\relax\@year=##3\relax
\ifnum\@day=1\relax 1\/$^{\mathrm{a\tilde{n}}}$\else
\number\@day\fi \space a\space viz\space
\monthnamewelsh[\@month]\space\number\@year}}%
```

If I redefine `\datewelsh` in the document like in the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[welsh]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\datewelsh{%
\renewcommand{\formatdate}[3]{%
\@day=##1\relax\@month=##2\relax\@year=##3\relax
\ifnum\@day=1\relax 1\/$^{\mathrm{a\tilde{n}}}$\else
\number\@day\fi \space %a\space viz\space
\monthnamewelsh[\@month]\space\number\@year}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\day=0
\loop\ifnum\day<10
  \advance\day by 1
  \today\endgraf
\repeat

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Not knowing how Welsh dates should appear this is the best I can do.

The “a viz” part seems to come from Breton (see `dt-breton.def`).

Comment: Thanks very much. Is it possible to get rid of the superscript stuff following the 1? (It would be OK if it was the right superscript stuff but it isn't. Welsh does not ever use the tilde accent that I know of and 'an' isn't right either.) Can I just remove the `\ifnum` stuff completely? I'd be tempted to try to do it properly but it would be somewhat more complicated since the superscripts would need to change for other numbers, too.

Comment: @cfr Just remove from `\ifnum` to `\fi`, leaving just `\number\@day`.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** To fix the earlier problem with spurious spacing, change the name of the file in `\ProvidesFile` to `dt-welsh.def` as well as renaming the file itself ([egreg's answer to my question about this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260970/how-can-i-eliminate-spurious-spacing-using-datetime-with-a-modified-def/260972)):

This is fixed version of `dt-welsh.def` based on [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203113/), [egreg's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203010/datetime-causes-incorrect-date-format-even-when-babel-is-loaded-first?noredirect=1#comment474083_203113) and the updated `gloss-welsh.ldf` from the new version of `polyglossia`.

The licence does not permit me to post a modified version of `dt-welsh.def` and I cannot figure out a clean way to load a differently named file. This is therefore named `dt-cymraeg.def` but ***will work only if renamed to `dt-welsh.def`.*** It cannot be distributed in that form, but it can be used in that form on your own system.

Hopefully `datetime` will eventually be fixed to do something a bit closer to producing correct output without the need for this. Certainly, the package has been updated to not include the `a viz`, which is something. The current bugs are copied from `babel` and the author is, I believe, aware of them. Perhaps this will help by providing correct patterns for Welsh.

```
%% dt-cymraeg.def
%% Additions and changes are copyright 2015 Clea F. Rees
%% Code from dt-welsh.def copyright 2015 Nicola Talbot (see below)
%% Code from gloss-welsh.ldf copyright 2008-2010 François Charette,
%% 2013 Élie Roux, 2011-2015 Arthur Reutenauer
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Clea F. Rees.
%
% This work consists of the file dt-cymraeg.def
%
% The file dt-cymraeg.def is a derived work under the terms of the
% LPPL. It is based on dt-welsh.def which is part of the datetime
% package by Nicola Talbot. A copy of datetime, including the
% unmodified version of dt-welsh.def is available from
% http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=datetime.
%
% The modifications are also derivative under the terms of the LPPL. They
% are based on code modified from gloss-welsh.ldf which is part of
% polyglossia 2015/08/06 v1.42.0 by François Charette, Élie Roux
% and Arthur Reutenauer. A copy of polyglossia, including gloss-welsh.ldf
% is available
% from http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=polyglossia.
%%
\ProvidesFile{dt-cymraeg.def}[$Id: dt-cymraeg.def 3789 2015-08-31 02:01:23Z cfrees $]
\providecommand*\dt@cymraeg@neges{%
  \PackageWarning{dt-cymraeg.def}{This is a MODIFIED version of dt-welsh.def. Breakage should under no circumstances be blamed on the author of the original file.}}
\dt@cymraeg@neges
\renewcommand*\dt@cymraeg@neges{\relax}
\providecommand*\ordinaldatewelsh[1]{%
  #1\ifcase#1\relax%
  \or\textsuperscript{af}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ail}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ydd}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ydd}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \else\textsuperscript{ain}\fi}%
\global\let\ordinaldatewelsh\ordinaldatewelsh
\providecommand\dayofweeknameidwelsh[1]{%
dydd\space%
\ifcase#1\relax
\or Sul%
\or Llun%
\or Mawrth%
\or Mercher%
\or Iau%
\or Gwener%
\or Sadwrn%
\fi}%
\global\let\dayofweeknameidwelsh\dayofweeknameidwelsh
\providecommand{\shortdayofweeknameidwelsh}[1]{%
\ifcase#1\relax%
\or Sul%
\or Llun%
\or Maw.%
\or Mer.%
\or Iau%
\or Gwen.%
\or Sad.%
\fi}%
\global\let\shortdayofweeknameidwelsh\shortdayofweeknameidwelsh
\providecommand{\monthnamewelsh}[1][\month]{%
\@orgargctr=#1\relax%
\ifcase\@orgargctr%
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
\or Ionawr%
\or Chwefror%
\or Mawrth%
\or Ebrill%
\or Mai%
\or Mehefin%
\or Gorffennaf%
\or Awst%
\or Medi%
\or Hydref%
\or Tachwedd%
\or Rhagfyr%
\else%
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
\fi}%
\global\let\monthnamewelsh\monthnamewelsh
\DeclareRobustCommand*\datewelsh{%
\renewcommand{\formatdate}[3]{%
  \@day=##1\relax\@month=##2\relax\@year=##3\relax
  \number\@day%
  \ifcase\@day\relax%
  \or\textsuperscript{af}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ail}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ydd}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ydd}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \else\textsuperscript{ain}%
  \fi%
  \space%
  \monthnamewelsh[\@month]\space\number\@year}%
}%
\global\let\datewelsh\datewelsh
\providecommand{\shortmonthnamewelsh}[1][\month]{%
\@orgargctr=#1\relax%
\ifcase\@orgargctr%
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 (jan.) to 12 (dec.)}% rhai o Yale ond 'dw i ddim yn cytuno â'i rhai Saesneg chwaith! (efaillai bod nhw'n safonol a ffurfiol?)
\or Ion.%
\or Chwe.% Chwef. yn ôl Yale??!!
\or Maw.%
\or Ebr.%
\or Mai%
\or Meh.%
\or Gorff.%
\or Awst.%
\or Medi%
\or Hyd.%
\or Tach.%
\or Rhag.%
\else%
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 (jan.) to 12 (dec.)}%
\fi}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file dt-cymraeg.def.
```

If you want to use this version, copy the contents to a file on your system. Save the file as `dt-welsh.def` and place it in your personal TEXMF tree or in your working directory. ***Make a note not to redistribute without renaming the file.*** Then things should work OK. ***Make another note to remember that you are using a modified version which will not, therefore, benefit from any updates or bug fixes to the package.***

In particular, ***do NOT report bugs to `datetime`'s author without checking that you can produce them*** **WITHOUT** ***this file in your TEXMF tree***.

As far as I can tell, this gets standard date formats right, as well as the long and short forms:

[image: fixed dates for Welsh]