# How can I eliminate spurious spacing using datetime with a modified .def?

Tags: spacing, datetime, welsh

I am trying to construct a corrected version of `dt-welsh.def` for use with the `datetime` package. In part, this is because my existing set up depends on `datetime` and, in part, it is because `datetime2` is much more complex and I can't figure out how to provide a suitable language module. (There is a module for Welsh but it is incorrect and unmaintained.) Since I really don't need the additional complexity, it would be nice to fix `datetime`.

Since `datetime` is considered deprecated by its author, the support for Welsh is not going to get fixed. So I'd like to figure out how to do it since there won't be an official fix.

The code works correctly in the standard case but introduces spurious spaces when using e.g. `\shortdate` or `\longdate` and I'm not sure how best to eliminate them.

Standard date formats:

[image: standard dates]

Short and long formats:

[image: buggy spacing]

```
\documentclass[welsh]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datetime}

\begin{document}

\day=0
\loop\ifnum\day<31
  \advance\day by 1
  \today
  \endgraf
\repeat

\day=0
\loop\ifnum\day<31
  \advance\day by 1
  \longdate\today
  \endgraf
\repeat

\day=0
\loop\ifnum\day<31
  \advance\day by 1
  \shortdate\today
  \endgraf
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Modified version of `dt-welsh.def`:

```
%% dt-cymraeg.def
%% Additions and changes are copyright 2015 Clea F. Rees
%% Code from dt-welsh.def copyright 2015 Nicola Talbot (see below)
%% Code from gloss-welsh.ldf copyright 2008-2010 François Charette,
%% 2013 Élie Roux, 2011-2015 Arthur Reutenauer
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Clea F. Rees.
%
% This work consists of the file dt-cymraeg.def
%
% The file dt-cymraeg.def is a derived work under the terms of the
% LPPL. It is based on dt-welsh.def which is part of the datetime
% package by Nicola Talbot. A copy of datetime, including the
% unmodified version of dt-welsh.def is available from
% http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=datetime.
%
% The modifications are also derivative under the terms of the LPPL. They
% are based on code modified from gloss-welsh.ldf which is part of
% polyglossia 2015/08/06 v1.42.0 by François Charette, Élie Roux
% and Arthur Reutenauer. A copy of polyglossia, including gloss-welsh.ldf
% is available
% from http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=polyglossia.
%%
\ProvidesFile{dt-cymraeg.def}[$Id: dt-cymraeg.def 3789 2015-08-31 02:01:23Z cfrees $]
\providecommand*\dt@cymraeg@neges{%
  \PackageWarning{dt-cymraeg.def}{This is a MODIFIED version of dt-welsh.def. Breakage should under no circumstances be blamed on the author of the original file.}}
\dt@cymraeg@neges
\renewcommand*\dt@cymraeg@neges{\relax}
\providecommand*\ordinaldatewelsh[1]{%
  #1\ifcase#1\relax%
  \or\textsuperscript{af}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ail}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ydd}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ydd}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \else\textsuperscript{ain}\fi}%
\global\let\ordinaldatewelsh\ordinaldatewelsh
\providecommand\dayofweeknameidwelsh[1]{%
dydd\space%
\ifcase#1\relax
\or Sul%
\or Llun%
\or Mawrth%
\or Mercher%
\or Iau%
\or Gwener%
\or Sadwrn%
\fi}%
\global\let\dayofweeknameidwelsh\dayofweeknameidwelsh
\providecommand{\shortdayofweeknameidwelsh}[1]{%
\ifcase#1\relax%
\or Sul%
\or Llun%
\or Maw.%
\or Mer.%
\or Iau%
\or Gwen.%
\or Sad.%
\fi}%
\global\let\shortdayofweeknameidwelsh\shortdayofweeknameidwelsh
\providecommand{\monthnamewelsh}[1][\month]{%
\@orgargctr=#1\relax%
\ifcase\@orgargctr%
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
\or Ionawr%
\or Chwefror%
\or Mawrth%
\or Ebrill%
\or Mai%
\or Mehefin%
\or Gorffennaf%
\or Awst%
\or Medi%
\or Hydref%
\or Tachwedd%
\or Rhagfyr%
\else%
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
\fi}%
\global\let\monthnamewelsh\monthnamewelsh
\DeclareRobustCommand*\datewelsh{%
\renewcommand{\formatdate}[3]{%
  \@day=##1\relax\@month=##2\relax\@year=##3\relax
  \number\@day%
  \ifcase\@day\relax%
  \or\textsuperscript{af}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ail}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ydd}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ydd}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{ed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \or\textsuperscript{eg}%
  \or\textsuperscript{fed}%
  \else\textsuperscript{ain}%
  \fi%
  \space%
  \monthnamewelsh[\@month]\space\number\@year}%
}%
\global\let\datewelsh\datewelsh
\providecommand{\shortmonthnamewelsh}[1][\month]{%
\@orgargctr=#1\relax%
\ifcase\@orgargctr%
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 (jan.) to 12 (dec.)}% rhai o Yale ond 'dw i ddim yn cytuno â'i rhai Saesneg chwaith! (efaillai bod nhw'n safonol a ffurfiol?)
\or Ion.%
\or Chwe.% Chwef. yn ôl Yale??!!
\or Maw.%
\or Ebr.%
\or Mai%
\or Meh.%
\or Gorff.%
\or Awst.%
\or Medi%
\or Hyd.%
\or Tach.%
\or Rhag.%
\else%
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 (jan.) to 12 (dec.)}%
\fi}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file dt-cymraeg.def.
```

## Background and Usage for Code

See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260784/ for background, caveats etc. The code posted above is a (partially) fixed version of `dt-welsh.def` based on [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203113/), [egreg's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203010/datetime-causes-incorrect-date-format-even-when-babel-is-loaded-first?noredirect=1#comment474083_203113) and the updated `gloss-welsh.ldf` from the new version of `polyglossia`.

The licence does not permit me to post a modified version of `dt-welsh.def` and I cannot figure out a clean way to load a differently named file. This is therefore named `dt-cymraeg.def` but must be renamed to `dt-welsh.def` to actually work. It cannot be distributed in that form, but it can be used in that form on your own system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spurious spaces are due to the name of the file. If I change the first line into

```
\ProvidesFile{dt-welsh.def}[2015/08/11]%
```

the file is not loaded a bunch of times and this avoids the spurious spaces:

[image]